# Chocolate Game: input loops without inserting loop or printing game stats

Tags: c++

I have been trying to do a Chocolate Manager game (more specifically a console test) and it loops just after I input the command! Ignoring the command value cin and the happiness... well I don't know what happens with happiness since it doesn't even show!

```
**Main.cpp**

// Include Space
//======
#include <iostream>
#include "timer.cpp"
#include <string>
#include "clrscr.cpp"
//======

using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool exit = false;
    int numchocolate = 15;
    double money = 25;
    string commandname;
    string commandvalue;
    string placeholder;
    double happiness;
    int cmdvl;

    while (exit == false) {
        commandname = "";  //Empties the variables so that they can be reused.
        commandvalue = ""; //
        cout << "Chocolate: " << numchocolate << "\nMoney:" << money << "\nCommand:"; //stats and initial prompt
        cin >> commandname; //Input for command name
        cout << "\nCommand value:"; //Second prompt
        cin >> commandvalue; //Input for command's value
        cmdvl = StringToNumber(&commandvalue); //Converts the string into a int. But this always fails for some reason....


        //Wait! I found the problem... wait, I don't know why it's caused so let's go on find more problems :3
        if (cmdvl == -1) {
            cout << "Something gone wrong in conversion! Exiting...";
            return 1;
        }

        if (commandname == "buy n chocolates") {
             numchocolate += buyChocolate(money, cmdvl);
        }
        else if (commandname == "eat n chocolates") {
            numchocolate -= cmdvl;
            happiness += cmdvl * 2.5;
        }
        else if (commandname == "go work n hours") {
            money += cmdvl * 2;
            happiness -= cmdvl / 3.5;
        }
        else if (commandname == "exit") {
            exit = true;
        }
        else {
            cout << "\nInvalid command! Happiness penalty!\n";
        }
        if (happiness > 101.0) {
            happiness = 101.0;
        }
        if (happiness > 1.0) {
            happiness -= 1.0;
        }
        cout << "\nNow you're " << happiness << "% happy.\n";
        cout << "Press Enter to continue to next simulation cycle.";
        placeholder = "";
        getline(cin, placeholder);
        ClearScreen();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Timer.cpp** (I know, nothing timer related)

```
// Include Space
//======
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
//======

using namespace std;

int buyChocolate(double money, int amount) {
    if (money > amount * 3.5) {
        return amount;
    }
    else if (money == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        double newAmont = money / 3.5;
        return (int) (newAmont);
    }
    return -1;
}

int StringToNumber ( const string * sometxt ) //Why do you always fail? :(
{
    stringstream ss(*sometxt); //A string stream declarer and initializer. Nothing much.
    int result; //Results are good :)
    return ss >> result ? result : -1; //Returns the int of the string. If it isn't int-compatible returns the error int -1.
}
```

**clrscr.cpp**

```
#include <windows.h>

void ClearScreen(){
    HANDLE                     hStdOut;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    DWORD                      count;
    DWORD                      cellCount;
    COORD                      homeCoords = { 0, 0 };

    hStdOut = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
    if (hStdOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return;

    /* Get the number of cells in the current buffer */
    if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hStdOut, &csbi )) return;
    cellCount = csbi.dwSize.X *csbi.dwSize.Y;

    /* Fill the entire buffer with spaces */
    if (!FillConsoleOutputCharacter(
    hStdOut,
    (TCHAR) ' ',
    cellCount,
    homeCoords,
    &count
    )) return;

    /* Fill the entire buffer with the current colors and attributes */
    if (!FillConsoleOutputAttribute(
    hStdOut,
    csbi.wAttributes,
    cellCount,
    homeCoords,
    &count
    )) return;

    /* Move the cursor home */
    SetConsoleCursorPosition( hStdOut, homeCoords );
}
```

It's main objective is to increase happiness while avoiding getting bankrupt or out of chocolate. Good luck (fixing AND playing)! :3

Oh and thanks to whoever made the clear screen code, as it's not mine and I forgot who made it... I want to avoid copyright issues before releasing the Console Version of the simple game and I don't know how :(

Also the code was updated but the string-to-int conversion don't work. I don't think debugging it will help since it is like obvious 4-line function and I already checked it like a thousand times!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I just fixed it! :) What do I do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you go through the code with the **Debugger** and set *break points* to see where exactly it stops and what error it drops.

And by the way you forgot a Semicolon ( ; ) here:

```
if (cmdvl == -1) {
    cout << "Something gone wrong in conversion! Exiting..." <-
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Code::Blocks has a debugger? wait, it has. Ok thanks! I'll see if that fixes.

Comment: I can't debug it because now if I try to rebuild the small changes I done to the code (which may contain the fix), it returns a error: "Can't access *build executable*: permission denied!" and it is worthless to debug a not-newest piece of code :/

Comment: Yes this may be caused if you already have and instance of the program opened, you may not see it but it runs in the background, go into the Task manager and find the "filename.exe" process and terminate it, but ofc Save any changes you made. Hope this helps

Comment: Wow, It was running in background! Heh, bad program! *hears a whine*

Anyway, thanks. I saved the changes, but they didn't fix the program... :( I tried some stuff.... but not many changes so no wonder it didn't fix :P

Comment: Well start debugging and post what errors you get

Comment: In Codeblocks an yellow arrow is at line 32 for some reason, it appeared after I debugged. It stops the program if the conversion don't work (i.e. an non-integer is inputted at the string commandvalue), but the conversion never works for some reason, even when I input a integer... Is it important?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99744/discussion-between-mcbooley-and-gustavo6046).

Answer (score 2):

start with using getline, cin reads to first white character:

```
        cout << "Chocolate: " << numchocolate << "\nMoney:" << money << "\nCommand:";
        getline(cin,commandname);
        cout << "\nCommand value:";
        getline(cin,commandvalue);
```

But the math seems to fail too.

```
Now you're 1.4822e-323% happy.
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, it actually contributed :) People just isn't giving attention to me nowadays, I probably done something but idk what. One of my answers got -3 for some reason (maybe because I was unclear if it worked) but anyway...